# RTL8723BE bluetooth and wifi not working simultaneously

Tags: 16.04

I'm a Linux newbie. I bought this laptop with the Realtek RTL8723BE wireless card.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

I've installed every possible driver from lwfinger and Pilot6's PPA as well.

But bluetooth and wifi don't work simultaneously. Whenever I turn on wifi, bluetooth disconnects and is very slow to discover.

I've also made a rtl8723be.conf file at /etc/modeprobe.d/ with the line :

```
options rtl8723be ant_sel=2 fwlps=0 swlps=0
```

Please help me resolve this.

Thank You